# Как подключать mongodb в nodejs? (es6, docker)

Tags: node.js, docker, mongodb, ecmascript-6

Запускаю монго у себя на локалке:

```
$ sudo docker run -it -v ~/Документы/git/mongodata:/data/db --name mongodb -d mongo

$ sudo docker ps
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE     COMMAND                  CREATED         STATUS         PORTS       NAMES
d2c970d1f3aa   mongo     "docker-entrypoint.s…"   8 seconds ago   Up 6 seconds   27017/tcp   mongodb
```

Установил через npm драйвер mongodb (версия 4.0.0-beta.1, стабильные версии 3.x почему-то отказались работать через import)

Код app.js:

```
import { MongoClient } from 'mongodb'
const client = new MongoClient('mongodb://localhost:27017', );
client.connect(async (err) => {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return;
    }
    console.log('Connected successfully to server');
    const db = client.db('myproject');
    const collection = db.collection('documents')
    try {
        const insertResult = await collection.insertMany([{ a: 1 }, { a: 2 }, { a: 3 }])
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);        
    }
    console.log('insertResult', insertResult);
    client.close();
});
```

возникает следующая ошибка:

```
MongoServerSelectionError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017
    at Timeout._onTimeout (/home/ivashka/Документы/git/anystory/node_modules/mongodb/lib/sdam/topology.js:301:38)
    at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:554:17)
    at processTimers (internal/timers.js:497:7) {
  reason: TopologyDescription {
    type: 'Unknown',
    servers: Map(1) { 'localhost:27017' => [ServerDescription] },
    stale: false,
    compatible: true,
    heartbeatFrequencyMS: 10000,
    localThresholdMS: 15,
    logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: undefined
  }
}
```

В чем причина ошибки и как исправить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это происходит из-за того, что вы не указываете флаг для привязки портов при запуске контейнера с `MongoDB` ([Docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#publish-or-expose-port--p---expose)), должно быть:

```
sudo docker run -it -p 27017:27017 ...
```

Такая команда привязывает порт `27017` на `localhost` к порту `27017` контейнера (они не обязательно должны быть одинаковыми, главно чтобы были не заняты другими приложениями). Тогда у вас начнет работать подключение по `localhost:27017`.

Если же вы в будущем захотите упаковывать и `nodejs` приложение в `Docker`, то эта опция вам уже не понадобится, т.к. внутри сети докера вы свободно сможете подключаться по имени контейнера, а выставлять базу "наружу" лишний раз не нужно.